# More efficient way to put an image on top of another - OpenCV Python3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have written a function that takes two images of equal size and returns a combined image of the same size such such that all **black pixels** (where the BGR value is [0, 0, 0]) of the first image will be replaced by **pixels of the second image.**

My code looks like this:

```
def combine(img1, img2):
    retImage = np.zeros((img1.shape[0], img1.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    for x in range(img1.shape[0]):
        for y in range(img1.shape[1]):
            if (0 not in img1[x][y]):
                retImage[x][y] = img1[x][y]
            else:
                retImage[x][y] = img2[x][y]
    return retImage
```

Obviously this is very slow, especially since I'm processing several 4k images in sequence. Is there a more efficient way to do this (preferably using OpenCV functions, like thresholding/masks)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code does what you want with Numpy operations which should be a lot more efficient than Python loops:

```py
pixel_has_zero = np.any(img1 == 0, axis=2, keepdims=True)    
retImage = np.where(pixel_has_zero, img2, img1)
```

This code is assuming that `img1` and `img2` are the same size. If that's not the case, you'll need to slice `img2` beforehand.